# Using email addresses with an apostrophe in devise rails

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am a new rails user and I am trying to create users with an apostrophe in their email. I have used the following piece of code and regex in the Devise gem initializer file.

```
config.email_regexp = "^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.']\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"
```

But when I tried to create a new user via rails console, it raised an error for the apostrophe.

Please guide on how to use emails with apostrophe with Devise gem.

Thanks

Comment: here are some easy to use email address regex validators http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email

Comment: In which part do u want the apostrophe?here u allow it after the @ and the apostrophe has to be followed by at least a word character

Comment: I want to use it as a'bc.def@example.com or abc.de'f@example.com both ways before @, i.e. within name characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
^\w+([-'.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

I have removed the + you added in the first character class. Add it if a literal + can be allowed.

This regex will allow **a'b@x.c**, **a'b-d@x.c** and **a'b-d@x.e.c**

and will not allow **a''b@x.c**, **a'-b-d@x.c** and **a'.b-d@x.e.c**

Comment: I got this error while trying to use the regex suggested by you.  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "bc"
LINE 1: ...sers".* FROM "users"  WHERE (users.email ILIKE 'a'bc.def@exa...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (users.email ILIKE 'a'bc.def@example.com') LIMIT 1

Comment: The apostrophe after a in 'a'bc.def@example.com' closes the value enclosing apostrophe opened before a. How is this query generated?if u have control over it, use double quotes to enclose the value as "a'bc.def@example.com". (I m not familiar with ruby or rails; just corrected the regex as u required)

Comment: The regex can just be used to check whether some text follows this particular pattern.